# Android Graphical layout doesnt show toggle button

Tags: android, eclipse, togglebutton, graphical-layout-editor

I'm new with android programming and i have a problem. I use Eclipse and i create a Toggle Button but in Graphical layout that doesn't show anything and it shows me this "Exception raised during rendering: -1". What can i do? I post below my code that i have used.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:padding="25dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etCommands"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Type a Command"
    android:password="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:id="@+id/bResults"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Try Command" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_weight="80"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:checked="true"
        android:id="@+id/tbPassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvResults"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="invalid" />
```

Comment: Could you post the whole xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended way to use "layout_weight" is to set the dimension to "0dp" and set the desired weight, so android will resize it:

```
<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="80"
    android:text="ToggleButton" />
```

I don't think this is the reason it crashes, so you better post the entire xml

----UPDATE----------------------------------------------

I don't get any rendering error, but as your button width is set to "fill_parent" (you should use "match_parent" instead as "fill_parent" is deprecated), and there are two items in a horizontal linear layout, the second one is not visible.

Also, use "0dp" when using weights for the intended dynamic dimension.

Here is your layout fixed. I also swapped weights so your buttons look better (I think it was a bug)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="25dp" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etCommands"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Type a Command"
    android:password="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bResults"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="80"
        android:text="Try Command" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/tbPassword"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:checked="true"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvResults"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="invalid" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort and for your time but i created a plain/white xml file and i drag and drop from graphical layout the toggle button icon and it shows me the following message:
 
"Exception raised during rendering: -1
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error LogThe graphics preview in the layout editor may not be accurate:
Different corner sizes are not supported in Path.addRoundRect. (Ignore for this session)"

Comment: Are you defining custom toggle buttons in your style? Did you try the layout in a fresh project?

Comment: What do u mean with the custon toggle button? Sorry i'm new with android and i dont know all the meanings. I created in the layout folder a new xml file and then i drag and drop a toggle button that it's been in the Form Widgets in graphical layout and then the above error is being popped out

Comment: You can define styles for views such as toggle buttons, but if you don't know about it then I'm sure you didn't. You might check which api is selected in the graphical editor or try the layout in a new empty project.

Comment: Where can i check which api is selected?

Comment: what can i say?! One more time i want to thank you for your time and for your effort. The problem was that i had selected one wrong AVD with wrong API. I really want to thank you!!!!